# How to force Windows 7 to complete safe mode boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

This computer (Windows 7 pro) boots up in normal mode, but I need to go into a Safe Mode command line.

When I try to boot it into safe mode it gets stuck loading the files. The same thing happens whether its safe mode command line or safe mode network version.

The fact that it can boot into normal mode suggests that the files are all there.

Unfortunately, I don't have any repair disks.

Comment: Probably worth you using a Windows 7 Pro disk and doing an `sfc /scannow` to see if there's corruption anywhere... doesn't make sense, especially with normal boot working, but worth a try.

Comment: How long does it get stuck for? It can take quite a long time compared to a normal boot.

Comment: " gets stuck loading the files." any particular file it gets stuck on?